# Обработка List<> через Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

Имеется класс, в котором есть поле Path directory; и метод, который возвращает список объектов - List getAllStorted.

Задача - реализовать этот метод, используя Files.list(directory).
Указанный метод возвращает Stream, а необходимо привести к List .
Пока что после всех просмотров про Stream'ы ничего не понял.
Прошу помощи; если не трудно - не только кусочком кода, но и небольшим пояснением

```
protected List<Resume> getAllStorage() {
    try {
        return Files.list(directory).collect(Collectors.toList());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new StorageException("Storage reading Error", null);
    }
}
```

В классе Resume - два поля String, геттеры/сеттеры/etc.

Дальше идет класс AbstractStorage, от которого наследуются различные классы с описанием типа хранения объектов класса Resume. Один из них - класс AbstractPathStorage, который реализует хранение объектов в виде файлов, в данном случае:

```
@Override 
protected void saveToStorage(Resume resume, Path path) { 
try { 
Files.createFile(path); 
} catch (IOException e) {
 throw new StorageException("Path creation Error", null);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Path> files = Files.list(directory).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: содержимое списка должно быть не Path, а один из классов пакета.
в данном случае List<Resume> files

Comment: @MaksimRybalkin добавьте в вопрос [mcve].

Comment: добавил в тело вопроса

Comment: Добавленный вами пример невоспроизводим. Код класса `Resume` нужен как минимум.

Comment: там содержится только два поля - fullName и uuid, геттеры/сеттеры, eqals/hashcode/comparator. Дальше идет класс AbstractStorage, от которого наследуются различные классы с описанием типа хранения объектов класса Resume. Один из них - класс AbstractPathStorage, который реализует хранение объектов в виде файлов
`@Override
    protected void saveToStorage(Resume resume, Path path) {
        try {
            Files.createFile(path);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new StorageException("Path creation Error", null);
        }
        updateInStorage(resume, path);
    }`